# Font Family URL Src "Unkown property name"

Tags: css

here is my code:

```
.icon-checkmark-usp:before {
    content: "î¤£";
    font-family: icomoon;
    src: url(fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff2) format("woff2");
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    z-index: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="usp-bar"><div class="usp-items"><i class="icon-checkmark-usp">Items</i></div></div>
```

The problem is, Developer Tools says now "Unkown property name" @ src and cross it out - so I don't get the item (normal check item) intead I get î¤£

[image]

Do someone know what the problem is?

Edit: I did the definition of the font with @font face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: icomoon;
    src: url(fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff2?2was9q) format("woff2");
}

.icon-checkmark-usp {
    content: "î¤£";
    font-family: icomoon;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    z-index: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility
}
```

But it's still not working.

Comment: See answer, its spot on. You can't define your font in a class, you need to define it in `@font-face {` and the use it with `font-family` in your class

Comment: It seems like you're using Icomoon the wrong way. Can't you just paste the `<link rel="stylesheet">` into your HTML, then use their preset HTML classes OR CSS-pseudo elements?

Comment: I want to inject items for a test with JS, I don't have access to the HTML file. Is this a Icomoon problem and can it be solved with any other free web font (example from google?) I only need the check item

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use web fonts, you must use `@font-face` to specify the font. See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: Thats what I did first

@font-face {
    font-family: icomoon;
    src: url(fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff2) format("woff2");
}

But it didn't work also (but i don't see anything in Developer Tools)

Comment: Read again: `.icon-checkmark-usp:before {` (copy/paste from your code)

Comment: Another example, see `Using The Font You Want`  and how it's called with `font-family`. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp  -- This answer is right, give the man his points...

Comment: Please see me edit - I did it with @font-face but it's still not working.

Comment: Now it looks good. Does the font exist under the given url? And did you check browser support for woff2 fonts?

Comment: Yes, but it's not working. Downloaded the font and tried it local, but same - the font will not apply and I don't know why

Comment: Does the font contain the characters you have in the `content`? And have you set the charset correctly? (`<meta charset="utf-8" />` - replace utf-8 with the one you use...)